# JavaFX: Click element in ScrollPane

Tags: javafx

I have the following node structure:

```
ScrollPane
    FlowPane
        ImageView
        ImageView
        ImageView
        ...
```

I added mouse events to the ImageViews which shall fire when they are clicked. But nothing happens. After looking for a while, I noticed that I can add a mouse event to the ScrollPane which then fire.

What do I have to do to make the ScrollPane and FlowPane pass the click events to my ImageViews?

Comment: First verify that they are visible.  If that is the case then watch out for any Nodes that may be above them and hence capturing the mouse events.  I have had this happen to me.  You do not need to worry about registering mouse events to the mimageview's parent Nodes.

Comment: Probably best to provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).